# Schrödinger's file

Tags: sh, archlinux, ext4

I am puzzled by the following sequence of commands.

```
sh-4.2$ pwd
/home/willard
sh-4.2$ ls -l f
-rwxr-xr-x 1 willard users 59116 Jan 23 14:54 f
sh-4.2$ file f
f: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0xea0e08ff2b5a062698d45b78177acdd6bf140d1f, stripped
sh-4.2$ ./f
sh: ./f: No such file or directory
sh-4.2$ strace ./f
execve("./f", ["./f"], [/* 32 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
sh-4.2$ ls -l f
-rwxr-xr-x 1 willard users 59116 Jan 23 14:54 f
sh-4.2$ uname -a
Linux xdat10 3.6.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 12 23:58:58 CEST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Someone is fooling you and quickly removed the file between the second and the third command you executed? (I cannot reproduce it using Ubuntu)

Comment: eek... what's the output of `ls f` before and after?

Comment: does this happen consistently? or was this a one time thing?

Comment: @davide-berra : Added the `ls f` (with a "-l" to show permissions), and a command showing my kernel version.
@aaron-waibel : This has never happened to me before. A friend of mine tried executing the binary on his Debian machine (from what I understand), and the file executes just fine. I am running a 64-bit OS, and the file is a 32-bit binary, but I do not believe this to be an issue, as my friend is also running a 64-bit OS. I haven't rebooted my computer for 3 months, and in the meantime, I have (almost certainly) fetched a new kernel through pacman. You think rebooting would help?

Answer (score 4):

I found someone having the same problem (with relative explanation)

[Running 32bit binary on a 64bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409)

Quoting the most important sentences:

> This situation often arises when you try to run a binary for the right
>   system (or family of systems) and superarchitecture but the wrong
>   subarchitecture. Here you have ELF binaries on a system that expects
>   ELF binaries, so the kernel loads them just fine. They are i386
>   binaries running on an x86_64 processor, so the instructions make
>   sense and get the program to the point where it can look for its
>   loader. But the program is a 32-bit program (as the file output
>   indicates), looking for the 32-bit loader /lib/ld-linux.so.2, and
>   you've presumably only installed the 64-bit loader
>   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 in the chroot.
>
> You need to install the 32-bit runtime system in the chroot: the
>   loader, and all the libraries the programs need. On Debian amd64, the
>   32-bit loader is in the libc6-i386 package. You can install a bigger
>   set of 32-bit libraries by installing ia32-libs.

I bet there's a better way to verify this but i'd try to exec

```
ldd ./f
```

and search in the output which loader is needed to exec'it

Answer (score 1):

man 2 execve:

```
ENOENT The file filename or a  script  or  ELF  interpreter  does  not
       exist,  or a shared library needed for file or interpreter can‐
       not be found.
```

You could run `ldd` against this binary to look for libraries that could not be mapped and install them from `multilib`.